# Add image attachment on already existed default shipping email magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, customer, email, image, attachment

I am trying to add the image as an attachment along with the shipping email when a customer is notified like this `$this->_shipmentNotifier->notify($orderShipment);`

can anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the content of an email via the template

Admin Panel > Marketing > Communications > Email Templates.

Then Add your image in the template content

Sources : [https://magefan.com/blog/customize-magento-2-email-templates#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20manage%20the,the%20Add%20New%20Template%20button](https://magefan.com/blog/customize-magento-2-email-templates#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20manage%20the,the%20Add%20New%20Template%20button).